# 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied - Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

We are trying to access the webservice from Docusing using  https://www.docusign.net/API/3.0/.
We are receiving Forbidden Access msg below.   We are unable to hit the URL from a browser also.

```
403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
```

During execution of the code we receive UnknownHostException when executing the below method.
The last line of code generates the error when creating a client.  We have validated our credentials and all appears to be in order.

```
public static APIServiceSoap getAPI(HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        DocuSignAPICredentials apiCreds = new DocuSignAPICredentials();
        apiCreds.setAccountId(session.getAttribute(Utils.SESSION_ACCOUNT_ID)
                .toString());
        apiCreds.setUserId(session.getAttribute(Utils.SESSION_USER_ID)
                .toString());
        apiCreds.setIntegratorsKey(session.getAttribute(
                Utils.SESSION_INTEGRATORS_KEY).toString());
        apiCreds.setPassword(session.getAttribute(Utils.SESSION_PASSWORD)
                .toString());
        apiCreds.setUserEmail(session.getAttribute(Utils.SESSION_EMAIL)
                .toString());
        apiCreds.setDocusignWebserviceEndpoint(session.getAttribute(
                Utils.DOCUSIGN_WEBSERVICE_ENDPOINT).toString());
        DocusignWebserviceFactory wsFactory = new DocusignWebserviceFactory();
        wsFactory.setEmail(apiCreds.getUserEmail());
        wsFactory.setIntegratorsId(apiCreds.getIntegratorsKey());
        wsFactory.setUserId(apiCreds.getUserId());

 // Error when executing the next line

        return wsFactory.setupClient(apiCreds.getDocusignWebserviceEndpoint())
                .authorizeAPI(apiCreds); 
    }   



Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: demo.docusign.net
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:227)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:377)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:539)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:170)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:407)

Please help me. Thanks.
```

Comment: Read the error. It looks like demo.docusign.net is causing issues.

Answer (score 2):

There is [java.net.UnknownHostException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/UnknownHostException.html) meaning that the IP address of the host cannot be determined. It is possible that you need a proxy to access the Internet from your LAN.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html) is a link explaining how to set it up with your java code but maybe Docusign API provides it.

Comment: We are trying to access the webservice from Docusing using https://www.docusign.net/API/3.0/. We are receiving Forbidden Access msg below. We are unable to hit the URL from a browser also.

403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied


https://www.docusign.net/API/3.0/ is generated by the WSDL file. The wsdl file i used are

https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx .

Please help me to resolve this. Thanks

Comment: Did you with the proy settings, as I suggested in my answer?
By the way,concerning the that access from the browser, were you correctly logged in when you attempted it?